# How to calculate sum of days within range over multiple years

Tags: excel, search, range, datediff, date-range

Is there a way to calculate the number of days within a range for a specific year?

For example, (my columns are Employee, Start Date, End Date, columns D-K=years 2009-2016) if my start date is 1/5/2008, and my end date is 6/9/2011, I want to know how many days elapsed in 2008, 2009, 2010, and 2011 between those years.

I've tried the following

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D$1,$B2))=TRUE,(DATEDIF($B2,$C2,"d"))/30,0)`

but that only returns the sum of days within the range for the earliest year and doesn't distribute the number of days over the following years if the range spans multiple years.

Comment: Why not use `B2 - B1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard formula for getting the overlap between two date ranges is

```
=MAX(MIN(end1,end2)-MAX(start1,start2)+1,0)
```

[See this reference for example](https://exceljet.net/formula/calculate-date-overlap-in-days)

so adapting it for your case where the years are given

```
=MAX(MIN($C2,DATE(D$1,12,31))-MAX($B2,DATE(D$1,1,1))+1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Do these columns needs to be in any certain format? This formula makes sense to me, and my data is set up exactly as you have it here, but when I apply the formula, it returns "365" for all years for 2009-2015 and "366" for 2016

Comment: Yes the start date and end date do have to be properly formatted as dates - I tried putting them in as text and you get the number of days in each year like you say - this is because the text value is ignored by the MIN and MAX functions and you're just left with e.g. 31/12/2016-1/1/2016+1=366 for 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Why divide by 30?

=DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d") works for me.

[image]

This should get you started... It needs work, but build upon this and you should be on your way.

[image]

```
=IF($B$2<DATE(D1,1,1), IF($C$2>DATE(D1,12,31), DATEDIF(DATE(D1,1,1),DATE(D1,12,31), "d"), DATEDIF(DATE(D1,1,1),$C$2,"d")),DATEDIF($B$2,DATE(D1,12,31),"d"))
```

Comment: I actually want the number of months, but if the start date is 1/10/11 and the end date is 4/7/11, for example, using "m" would only return "2" even though it's closer to 3 months

Comment: How about trying to force an extra month... =IF(MOD(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d"),30)>=15, DATEDIF(B2,C2,"m")+1, DATEDIF(B2,C2,"m"))

Comment: The issue is really that I need to know how many days are included in that range FOR EACH YEAR. So the total 1251 days is not what I'm looking for - I want to know how many of those days were in 2008, 2009, 2010, and 2011.